# Bootstrap modal and Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

With Django, I have a loop of div. On click on div, I want a modal show.

My code HTML :

```
{% for object in theobjects %}
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:0.5%;">
        <div name="traitement" <!-- onclick="click_traitement('{{object.name}}')"--> data-toggle="modal" data-target="traitement_{{objet.name}}" class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <b>{{ object.name}}</b>.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
                    <i> {{ object.text }} </i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- start modal -->
            <div id='traitement_{{objet.name}}' name="traitement" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title"> 
                                                        Profile of <b> {{ object.name }} </b> 
                                                    </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top:18%;">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    {{ object.text }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="row" style="text-align:center;margin-top:5%;">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Quit</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End modal -->

      </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

My code JQuery :

```
function click_traitement(name){
    $("#traitement_"+name).modal('show');

}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div[name=traitement]').hover(function(){
                $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'});
      });
});
```

The first time, when I click on the div with the id="traitement_{{object.name}}", it works (the modal is show). But when I clode this modal and I want open it again, It don't works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try setting the following properties to your div named "traitement" instead of using onclick():

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="traitement_{{objet.name}}"
```

Although it may not matter, but both of your div have the same name - "traitement".

Comment: Can you check / send the generated final html code. We can figure out what exactly is the problem after that..

Comment: I don't understand, how check/send the generated final html code ? I edited the post

Comment: Whatever browser you are using will have an option to 'view source'. Check the final html file and that should give you hints. 'Ctrl+u' gives the html source code in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I check this and it's good. I have 3 objects in my loop so I have 3 modals whith differents id... I think when I close the modal the first time, isn't really closed. Secondly I think your idea not works because in the div "traitement", there are the modals. They not separeted...

Comment: LOL, finally I resolve the problem with your help. I use your idea, just us have forgot the "#" :  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#traitement_{{objet.name}}". Thank you very much !